# Show that the set of affine motions is a group.

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about group theory.  There was a problem given in the book:

> An affine motion of $\mathbb {R}^2$ is a bijective mapping of the form $T_{Av}:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T_{Av}(x)=A\underline{x} +\underline{v}$ for $x,v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ where $A\underline {x}$  is given by the left multiplication of the matrix $A$ with the column matrix $\underline {x}$. Show that the set of affine motions is a group under composition of mapping .

However, I am not getting what do they mean by $\underline{v}$? Is it a constant column matrix ? Also how to prove it ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: For each $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and each $v \in \mathbb R^{2}$ you have transformation $T_{Av}$. The proof is not difficult. Try to do it yourself and seek help if you get stuck.

Comment: From the context, I would guess that maybe $v$ is used to denote an abstract $2$-tuple of elements in $\mathbb{R}$, while $\underline{v}$ is viewed explicitly as a column vector. Other than that, one just has to check the group axioms.

Comment: @geetha290krm but do we have functions like $T_{Av}T_{Bv},...$, etc in that group? Then when we do closure property like $T_{Av}\circ T_{Bv}(x)=AB\underline {x}+A\underline{v}+\underline {v}$, and so, closure property is satisfied , right? Next, if we check for identity property if $A=I$(,where $I$ is the identity matrix) , will $T_{Iv}$ be the identity element,  why? ...

Comment: You have to consider functions like $T_{A,v}$ and $T_{Bw}$. ($v$ is also varying).

Comment: @Franklin : the notations are horrible. It is difficult to reflect on such an exercice, however simple it may be, with such unsuitable notations; it would be worth explaining them to you in order to return then reasonably to healthier notations.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen but this is how it was given in the book ...I posted it as it was...so maybe I  have nothing to do about it...sorry...but I cant quite get how to do it...

Comment: Yes I understood :) ; don't take this the wrong way, my complaint is for the use of such inappropriate notations. As they say back home, in France, a mother wouldn't recognize her little ones there.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen It' alright...no problem...

Comment: *Which book are you referring to?*

Comment: You ask questions, that's good; but shouldn't you be a little interested in the answers that are offered to you? (you can ask questions about the answers that are offered to you if there are points in the answers that you do not understand, you can even be critical if it seems relevant to you,...)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen What exactly do u mean? I don't quite get u...questions are posted to get answers in the site...

Comment: What I mean exactly is that once an answer has been given, it seems to me the most basic courtesy(given that it is a voluntary work on the part of the one who takes the time to answer your question), to take an interest in the answer given, for example by asking about such and such a point in the answer, before going to ask other questions, as you do.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen If u don't mind...but this is a question given on the basic chapter of group theory..I have just started learning about group theory and I dont know anything about "affine application " or "affine bijective application " ...the chapter only requires to solve the problems using the axioms of being a group and only on that...so I am not getting what u wrote...I want to know how the closure property, associative property, identity property and inverse property is satisfied...

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $E$ be a real vector space. We define an affine *application* $t$ : it's an application $t:E\to E$ such that there exists $v\in E$, $a:E \to E$ linear, such that : $$\forall x \in E, t(x)=v+a(x)$$.
2. Let's proof that $v$ and $a$ are uniquely determined by $t$. We necesserely have $v=t(0)$, where $0$ is the origin of $E$. Then, for $x\in E$, we necesseraly have $a(x)=t(x)-t(0)$. Q.E.D. We can now note $t_{a,v}$ but we won't because it is cumbersome.

3.We define an affine motion of $E$ as an affine *bijective* application.

4.We prove that $t$ is an affine motion iff $a$ is bijective.

5. Let us come back to $E=\mathbb R ^2$. Let $v=(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb R^2$. $\underline{v}=\begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\y_0\end{bmatrix}$.
6. With the notations that I introduced, it should be easier to prove the claims.

Answer (score 0):

With the notations from my previous answer,

1. First, we will show that we have an internal composition law on the set $G$ of affine mappings from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$. Let $t_1=t_{a_1,v_1}$ and $t_2=t_{a_2,v_2}$ be two affine mappings. $\forall x\in \mathbb R^2, t_2(x)=v_2+a_2(x), t_1(t_2(x))=v_1+a_1(v_2+a_2(x))=v_1+a_1(v_2)+a_1(a_2(x))$ since $a_1$ is linear. So $t_1\circ t_2 \in G$
2. $id_{\mathbb R^2}$ is the neutral element;
3. $\circ$ is associative(associativity for mappings);
4. Let $H$ be the set of affine *motions*; we know that $t=t_{a,v}$ is bijective iff $v\in GL(\mathbb R^2)$. Let $x, y\in \mathbb R^2. y=a+v(x)\iff y-a=v(x) \iff x=v^{-1}(y-a)\iff x=v^{-1}(y)-v^{-1}(a) \iff t^{-1}(y)=-v^{-1}(a)+v^{-1}(y) \iff t^{-1}=t_{-v^{-1}(a),v^{-1}}$. So $t$ has an inverse in $H$;
5. From 1, 2, 3 and 4, we deduce that the set of affine motions is a group under composition of mappings .Q.E.D.